# WebGL: Texture rendering not working correctly

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I'm trying to use textures for the first time in WebGL and I'm having a problem getting it to work. I'm trying to apply a stone-like texture to cubes that are moving around in a 3D space, as you can see in the rocks.js below. I always get this error which I don't know what to make of (I'm using Chrome btw):

> RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0

Here is my index.html file:

```
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

void main()
{
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void
main()
{
     gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, fTexCoord );
    //gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="spaceship.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rocks.js"></script>
<body>
 <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="1100" height="1200" style="float:left;">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
 </canvas>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my rocks.js where the object which I'm attempting to apply texture to is defined:

```
    // global webgl variables
var gl;

var vBuffer;
var cBuffer;
var iBuffer;
var tBuffer;
var mvLoc;

var rocks = (function() {

    var direction = vec3();
    var lastDirection = vec3();
    var location = vec3();
    var lastLocation = vec3();

    var rock = {
        NumVertices : 36,

        indices :[
            1, 0, 3,
            3, 2, 1,
            2, 3, 7,
            7, 6, 2,
            3, 0, 4,
            4, 7, 3,
            6, 5, 1,
            1, 2, 6,
            4, 5, 6,
            6, 7, 4,
            5, 4, 0,
            0, 1, 1
        ],

        vertices : [
            vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
            vec4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
        ],

        texVertices : [
            vec2(-0.5, -0.5),
            vec2(-0.5, 0.5 ),
            vec2( 0.5, 0.5 ),
            vec2( 0.5, -0.5 ),
            vec2( -0.5, -0.5 ),
            vec2( -0.5, 0.5 ),
            vec2( 0.5, 0.5 ),
            vec2( 0.5, -0.5 )
        ],

        render : function(mv) {

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(this.vertices));

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Uint8Array(this.indices))

            gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
            gl.bufferSubData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(this.texVertices) );


            mv = mult( mv, scalem(0.2, 0.2, 0.2) );
            mv = mult( mv, translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );

            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, false, flatten(mv));
            gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, this.NumVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
        }
    }

    var init = function(glIn, vBufferIn, iBufferIn, tBufferIn, mvLocIn) {
        // set global webgl variagles
        gl = gl;
        vBuffer = vBufferIn;
        iBuffer = iBufferIn;
        mvLoc = mvLocIn;
        tBuffer = tBufferIn;


        direction = [(Math.random()*0.06-0.03)/2, (Math.random()*0.06-0.03)/2, (Math.random()*0.06-0.03)/2];
        location = [Math.random()*6-3, Math.random()*6-3, Math.random()*6-3];
        lastDirection = direction;
        lastLocation = location;
    }

    var render = function(spinX, spinY, mv) {
        mv = mult( mv, rotateX(spinX) );
        mv = mult( mv, rotateY(spinY) );
        mv = mult( mv, translate(location) );

        rock.render(mv);
    }

    var updateRock = function() {
        // direction = updatedDir;
        location = add( location, direction );

        if(location[0] > 3 || location[0] < -3) location[0] = -location[0];
        if(location[1] > 3 || location[1] < -3) location[1] = -location[1];
        if(location[2] > 3 || location[2] < -3) location[2] = -location[2];

        lastDirection = direction;
        lastLocation = location;
    }


    return {
        init : init,
        render : render,
        update : updateRock
    };
});
```

And finally, my main.js for running everyting:

```
// webgl global variables
var gl;
var canvas;

var texture;

var texCoords = [];

var movement = false;
var spinX = 0;
var spinY = 0;
var origX;
var origY;

var xRot = 0;
var yRot = 0;

var grid;
var spaceship;
var rocksArray = [];

function configureTexture( image ) {
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
}


window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 128, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 128, gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vTexCoord" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "rock.jpg"
    image.onload = function() {
      configureTexture( image );
    }

    var proLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projection" );
    mvLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelview" );
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "texture"), 0);


    var pers = perspective( 100.0, 1.0, 0.2, 100.0 );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(proLoc, false, flatten(pers));

    grid = new grid();
    grid.init(gl, vBuffer, cBuffer, iBuffer, mvLoc);

    spaceship = new spaceship();
    spaceship.init(gl, vBuffer, cBuffer, iBuffer, mvLoc);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        rocksArray[i] = new rocks();
        rocksArray[i].init(gl, vBuffer, iBuffer, tBuffer, mvLoc);
    }

    attachEventHandlers();

    render();
}

function reloadPage() {
    location.reload();
}

function attachEventHandlers() {

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
        movement = true;
        origX = e.offsetX;
        origY = e.offsetY;
        // Disable drag and drop
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
        movement = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        if(movement) {
            spinY += (e.offsetX - origX) % 360;
            spinX += (e.offsetY - origY) % 360;
            origX = e.offsetX;
            origY = e.offsetY;
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      spaceship.keyArray[e.keyCode] = true;
    });

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      spaceship.keyArray[e.keyCode] = false;
    });

}


function render() {
  spaceship.moveSpaceship();


  rocksArray.forEach(function(rock) {
      rock.update();
  });

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mv = lookAt( vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) );
    mv = mult(mv, rotateX(90));

    // spaceship.render(spinX, spinY, mv);
    mv = mult( mv, translate(-xVal, -yVal, -zVal));
    mv = mult(mv, rotateZ(-zSpin));
    mv = mult(mv, rotateX(-xSpin));


    grid.render(spinX, spinY, mv);

    rocksArray.forEach(function(rock) {
        rock.render(spinX, spinY, mv);
    });

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely you start rendering immediately but your texture doesn't get created until the image has downloaded.

My suggestion is to create a 1x1 pixel texture to start, then replace the contents of that texture with the image once it has downloaded.

```
function configureTexture( image ) {
    // texture = gl.createTexture(); -- delete this line
    ...
}
```

And change your initialization to something like

```
texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
// put a 1x1 red pixel in the texture so it's renderable immediately
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255]));

// now load the image, the image will replace the contents of the
// texture once it has finished downloading
var image = new Image();
image.src = "rock.jpg"
image.onload = function() {
  configureTexture( image );
}
```

[I'd suggest taking a look at these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)